# Getting RWBoundsErr while reading a text file using RWCString in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, file-handling, fileoutputstream, rogue-wave

Following code is giving me **RWBoundsErr** error

> *terminate called after throwing an instance of 'RWBoundsErr'*

```
bool filterData()
{       
    while(!inputFile_.eof())
    {
        currentLine_.readLine(inputFile_);        
        //outputFile_<<currentLine_(0,1)<<currentLine_(2,1)<<currentLine_(4,13)<<currentLine_(0,1)<<currentLine_(2,1)<<currentLine_(4,13)<<endl;
        outputFile_<<currentLine_[0]<<currentLine_[2]<<currentLine_(4,13)<<currentLine_[0]<<currentLine_[2]<<currentLine_(4,13)<<endl;        
    }
    return (TRUE);
}
```

But if I use the commented out line instead, everything is working as expected.

**currentLine_** is of data type [RWCString](http://docs.roguewave.com/sourcepro/11/html/toolsref/rwcstring.html)

outputFile_ and inputFile_ has the path of the inout/output txt files

Sample contents of the text file

```
ABCD1234567890123 2017/10/16 13:40:28 
WXYZ9876543210987 2017/10/16 13:40:28
```

Please note that there is a trailing space at the end of each line

Even though I have identified the solution to this issue, I would like to understand why this code is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation related to `operator<<()` operator for `RWCString`:

```
RWvostream&
operator<<(RWvostream&, const RWCString& str);
RWFile&
operator<<(RWFile&,     const RWCString& str);
Saves string str to a virtual stream or RWFile, respectively.
```

and `RWFile`:

```
RWFile&
operator<<(RWFile&,     const RWCString& str);
Saves string str to a virtual stream or RWFile, respectively.
...
RWFile&
operator<<(RWFile&,     const RWInteger& x);
Saves the RWInteger x to a virtual stream or RWFile, respectively.
```

There is no `<<` operator which would take a `char`.

`currentLine_(0,1)` is a substring which can be used with `<<` operator

```
RWCSubString
operator()(size_t start, size_t len);
RWCConstSubString
operator()(size_t start, size_t len) const;
```

On the other hand the `currentLine_[0]` is a `char`

```
char&
operator[](size_t i);
char
operator[](size_t i) const;
Returns the ith byte.
```

In your case the attempt to use `char` with the `<<` operator causes the `RWBoundsErr` error.

Comment: [Documentation for RWvostream](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3702/vos_5157.htm) says that char is allowed with **<<** operator

Comment: @AnishKumar That is true. But in your  case you do not stream with `RWvostream`